# use react.js inside android webview webapp

Tags: android, reactjs, web-applications, webview

I want to use the react.js+antd+react-router+react-redux package files (can run in a general browser) embedded in the Android WebView, but can't run up a blank page, I don't use ordinary JS script to run, and used this way to integrate webapp's brother for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript normally when access it from a WebView, just need to activate it. Try this with your WebView

```
WebView webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```